# Creating foreign JNDI settings in weblogic and lookup from Java client

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi, ldap-query, ldapconnection

Please post if there is any example/steps to configuring external LDAP and execute LDAP queries on it.

I tried the following

- creating Foreign JNDI Providers
- Created remote and local JNDI names
- from servlet client, I tried lookup using foreign jndi name, local and remote jndi names

Finally lookup with local name succeeded, unfortunately that tried to connect localhost:389. Not sure what went wrong.

Please help with any example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a *Foreign JNDI Provider*.
2. Initial context factory: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (i was using openDS LDAP)
3. Provider URL : "ldap://localhost:389"
4. User as:  cn=Directory Manager
5. Password: give LDAP password.
6. Properties:

   ```
   com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true
   com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.maxsize=16
   com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize=10
   com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=600000
   java.naming.referral=follow
   java.naming.security.authentication=simple
   ```
7. Create a Foreign JNDI link

   ```
   linkname : testLink
   localJndi : testLocalJNDI
   Remote JNDI :  dc=test,dc=org (LDAP BASE DN)
   ```

Now you can access the LDAP from your code using the "testLocalJNDI".

Cheers, Karai

Answer (score 0):

As I experienced, it is not possible to link a whole ldap tree under weblogic jndi.
Foregin jndi link supports only side-by-side jndi object linkage.

I cannot understand the previous answer why gives a solution to this thread.